# trick behind mixpanel homepage animation?

Tags: css, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

On its homepage [mixpanel.com](http://mixpanel.com) when you start scrolling downwards , the lower div element appears to be overflowing over the previous elements.
How do we achive that ?

Comment: google: parallax scrolling

Comment: just the term I was looking for!! Thank You..:)